# Need to change the back ground position on each mouse move

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I need to change the back ground position on each mouse move. Image is set as background, here is the image,

https://pbdlbd.org/ipositive/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/one10.jpg

and i want to move the background position on each mouse move. This image has 4 parts(height of each part is 523px) and first it will show the top portion and after mouse move over  it will show the 2nd portion and on another mouse move it will show 3rd portion and after 4th part it will repeat for further mouse move over it. After mouse is removed from the image, it will show the default top portion of the image.

Something like this,

```
document.getElementById("#ipos .flex_cell").onmousemove = function() {
  //Set background position 523px bottom on each mouse move
  #ipos .flex_cell.style.background-position = center -523px (here i can't make it so that it changes to -1046px by code);
}
```

Here is the site, http://pbdlbd.org/ipositive/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.mousemove` to get every instance of a mouse move. This will register for every pixel. So I popped it into a loop and divided the count for each mouse move by 40 (feel free to change this accordingly). Every time the mouse moves by 40 pixels then I add a class to the image to move it up for each of the stages and it resets once it's cycled through. See the code below and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbnytpzv/) is a fiddle. Hope it makes sense and best of luck!

```js
$('.wrapper').on('mouseover' , function(){
var count = 0;
 $('.wrapper').on('mousemove' , function(){
   var move = count/40;
    if (move==1){
      $('.image').addClass('second');
    }
    if (move==2){
      $('.image').addClass('third');
    }
    if (move==3){
      $('.image').addClass('fourth');
    }
   count++;
    if(move>=4){
      count=0;
        $('.image').removeClass('fourth third second');
        return count;
    }
  });
});
$('.wrapper').on('mouseout' , function(){
 $('.image').removeClass('fourth third second');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 217px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image{
  width:100%;
}
.second{
  margin-top:-217px;
}
.third{
  margin-top:-435px;
}
.fourth{
  margin-top:-652px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="image" src="http://pbdlbd.org/ipositive/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/one10.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jumps from 1st to 4th part you simply have to read (or read from a seperate variable) the current position and add the offset and set this sum as target.

You also have to use an if-condition in the function to detect the jump from the 4th part back to the 1st.

So could would be (untested):

```
var offset = 0;
var jump = 523;

$('#ipos .flex_cell').mousemove(function () {
    if (offset > (3 * jump)) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    else {
        offset += jump;
    }

    $('#ipos .flex_cell').css('background-position', 'center ' + (offset * -1) + 'px');
});
```

BUT: This is only the answer to your question but it does not solve the problem. Because a mousemove is EVERY PIXEL you move over the element.. so this code would procude massiv flickering. So you should also remember last cursor position and only act on a defined move distance.

BR Tim